# Does Firefox support TLS on non-standard ports?

Tags: ssl, firefox

My presumption was that TLS 1.0+ is supported by Firefox on ports other than 443. However, a tweet crossed my path that seems to debunk this.

> Turns out that Firefox does not support TLS on any port that is not 443 … #poodle #sigh

@bramus - https://twitter.com/bramus/status/522419071540002817?s=09

I was unable to find any supporting evidence for this statement. Does it hold any truth?

If so, this would imply that only SSL 3 is supported on ports other than 443, which would make evading POODLE more problematic.

Would you recommend a method by which we could test this (proving it one way or the other)?

**Edit**

The example given in a reply to the above tweet is cpanel.ikdoeict.be:2087. If the claim is false, perhaps there is an alternative explanation as to why Firefox would not connect to such a host after disabling SSL 3?

Comment: I feel like this is more a Firefox support question than a security question.

Comment: a packet capture would 'prove it'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt this has anything to do with the port (why would it?). It works for me on my own server (lighttpd) on a non-standard port. The difference to the example in the Tweet is that my server supports TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2, while the example only has TLS1.2 (and a more limited number of ciphers).

Works in Firefox 24.8.1:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
```

Does **not** work in Firefox 24.8.1:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.0: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.1: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
```

Output from `nmap --script +ssl-enum-ciphers`

Comment: As a follow-up: It would be nice to get a list of supported TLS1.2 cipher suites for Firefox/NSS. What is already apparent from the second cipher list is that none of the cipher suites offer PFS (Perfect Forward Secrecy) as there is no DHE (Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral) to be found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to mention the example the twitter user gave, and to ask for alternative explanations like yours! I'm not sure if the following provides enough info for your follow-up? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Firefox&version=24.2.0%20ESR&platform=Win%207

Comment: The link you provided lists the TLS versions support for Firefox 24.2.0 ESR. As you can see, TLS1.2 is not supported which is why this example would not work with the cpanel-example. Trying with Firefox 24.8.1 on Linux gives me the same result, so that would be the explanation for this site not working.